# Is there a way to require a typescript file inside a javascript file?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, typescript

I created a project using `ng`.
I called `ng eject` to get a webpack.config.js.
I added pug to the webpack.
I want to pass the data from src/environments/environment.ts to pug but I can't figure out how to require the typescript file from a normal javascript file.

I can always change environment.ts to a json file or javascript file but would like to leave it the way it is.

Here is the environment.ts file

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  title: 'My App DEV'
};
```

Answer (score 1):

As long as it is actually valid JavaScript (not TypeScript), as your example is, then yes. You'll just need to include/require it including the extensions:

```
require('./environment.ts');
// or
import environment from './environment.ts';
```

If it were to contain TypeScript code, you'd need to transpile it to regular JavaScript at some point. Where/when/how you do that would be up to your build pipeline.